# Периодическая фоновая синхронизация в приложении Android

Tags: android, синхронизация

Прошу поделиться опытом в вопросе фоновой синхронизации в приложении. Например, требуется каждые 30 мин. делать запрос серверу через Retrofit, сравнивать с локальной бд, если есть новые записи, обновлять локальную бд и высылать уведомление.Знаком с Alarm Manager, SyncAdapter и WorkManager. Хотел узнать, что на данный момент актуально, какие библиотеки и фреймворки используют профи в современных приложениях.

Answer (score 0):

На текущий момент самым серьезным игроком выглядит `WorkManager` (для вашей задачи там есть периодическое выполнение работы), так как он будет корректно работать на любой версии Android.